# How to specify CA private key password for client certificate creation using OpenSSL

Tags: command-line, openssl, x509, ca

I am building a command line script to create a client certificate using OpenSSL "mini CA" feature.

I have a **CA certificate** and **CA private key encrypted with a password**. With those things I am trying to create the client certificate and stumbled upon the command line syntax. *How do I specify the password for the CA's private key?*

So far, I have ...

```
openssl x509
  -req
  -in client.csr
  -signkey client.key
  -passin pass:clientPK
  -CA client-ca.crt
  -CAkey client-ca.key 
  -CAkeypassin pass:client-caPK <-- does not work
  -CAcreateserial
  -out client.crt
  -days 365
```

See the highlighted parameter. I expect something like this, but I cannot find it anywhere in the docs.

### Corrected

Just for the records. The `-signkey` parameter is used for self signed certificates. CA's don't have access to the client's private key and so will not use this. Instead the `-passin` parameter refers to the CA's private key.

```
openssl x509
  -req
  -in client.csr
  -CA client-ca.crt
  -CAkey client-ca.key 
  -passin pass:CAPKPassword
  -CAcreateserial
  -out client.crt
  -days 365
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Comment: Yep... Voted to close and migrate to SuperUser.

Comment: Yeah, writing openssl commands isn't actually programming -it just feels like it.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use `-passin pass` as shown below.

```
 openssl x509
      -req
      -in client.csr
      -signkey client.key
      -passin pass:clientPK
      -CA client-ca.crt
      -CAkey client-ca.key 
      -passin pass:secret <-- try this
      -CAcreateserial
      -out client.crt
      -days 365
```

Comment: You are right. I made a mistake by adding the `-signkey` parameter and so the password that is already in there marked with `-passin` parameter refers to the client's private key - which is actually not available for the CA.

Comment: what's the meaning of each part of "passin" parameter ? What is "pass" and what is "secret" ?

Comment: Verbatim "pass" means password is given in command line and secret should be substituted with actual password. There are options to supply password with file/fd, see `man openssl` for details.

Comment: Is it normal/intended to have the "passin" argument present several times? Isn't the first one simply replaced by the second one?